# How to find entered date already exist in min and max date?

Tags: c#

I am struggling with a problem.  I want to check whether the `TextBox` date already exists in my selected minimum and maximum dates.

Code snippet:

```
str = "Select Min(Fromdate), Max(Todate)  From LeaveApply where Status='approved'";
dr = conn.query(str);

if (dr.Read())
{
     string mindate = dr[0].ToString();
     string maxdate = dr[1].ToString();

     str = "select top 1 EmpCode  From Musterroll WHERE '" + 
           txtdate.Text + "'>='" + maxdate + 
           "' and '" + txtdate.Text + "'<='" + mindate + 
           "' and  Status='" + approved + "' order by EmpCode desc";
     dr = conn.query(str);

     if (dr.Read())
     {
         string code= dr[0].ToString();
     }
}
```

Query does not throw any exceptions; however, `string code=dr[0].ToString()`does not return any values.

Comment: Are you sure your `dr.Read()` returns `true` in your second if statement? Did you debug your code? And you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: @Soner Gönül,No it not returns any value

Comment: If it is not, how do you think your code reach `string code= dr[0].ToString()` part if `dr.Read()` is `false`?

Comment: @Soner Gönül, I said the same.I cheked with break point, it not enter inside the second if condtion after read query it goes out of second if condition

Comment: William, could you fix the first line of your code.  That would produce a compiling error... and I don't want to change the code, since I'm not sure exactly what you have.

Comment: Please rewrite your code using parameterized SQL queries... It may also fix your issues at the same time if errors come from incorrect query resulting from string concatenation.

Comment: @B.K., May I know the error bcz it works fine for me(the first line of my query)

Comment: @WilliamBlane `str = "Select Min(Fromdate), Max(Todate)  From LeaveApply where Status='approved'` That is syntactically wrong.  No semicolon, no closing quote.

Comment: What's the database engine? SQL-Server?

Comment: @bansi: I don't think so. txtdate.Text obviously is not a column name.

Comment: @Jenny O'Reilly, txtdate.text is my textbox value(entered date)

Comment: I vote to close this question because it is totally _unclear what you asking_.

Comment: Your second query doesn't make sense to me. You have WHERE conditions that do not depend on any of the table's columns. You could move that condition out of SQL to your C# code and then the query becomes simpler and you'll see that it doesn't make sense. Think again about your query and maybe post your table setup and what you are actually trying to find out.

Comment: @SonerGönül: I think the question is quite clear. His second statement does not deliver a result and he does not know why and how to look for the problem.

Comment: @Uwe, yes I dnt know how to  make clear my question more than this

Comment: @WilliamBlane Look at the comment from Jenny O'Reilly before my last comment. I think this could be one of your problems that you are not referencing column names.

Comment: @Uwe, yes Jenny O'Reilly is correct its my query mistake..I will try to clear it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

i have changed the >= and <= condition, and also hardcoded approved as status.

```
str = "select top 1 EmpCode  From Musterroll WHERE '" + txtdate.Text + "' <= (Select Max(Todate)  From LeaveApply where Status='approved') and '" + txtdate.Text + "' >= (Select Min(Fromdate)  From LeaveApply where Status='approved') and Status='approved' order by EmpCode desc";
```